# In oracle how to minus four hours on date field and also show milliseconds

Tags: sql, oracle, tableau-api

I used this function:
`to_char(completed_date - interval '4' hour,'YYYY-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS.FF')`
it works correctly, but when I embed the code into tableau then I am getting an error as invalid month, If I convert that to string column then I don't see any error. But I don't want to convert the date field as other data type except datetime data type.
How can I achive this?
I want to convert in sql code itself, because I have to pass date parameter values to code.

DateTime field in table is stored in this format:
`2020-11-29 14:06:46.963`

Comment: Why do you want to subtract 4 hours? If you are trying to convert between time zones then don't use that method; instead use `FROM_TZ( completed_date, 'UTC' ) AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern'` (if, for example, you were converting from UTC to EST/EDT) as it will automatically handle daylight savings time.

Comment: thanks a lot for your comment, this really helps.. I am changing to guyana time zone 'GMT-4' zone. can you please show this in the function, because when I do GMT-4 in the place of UTC it is throwing an error –

Comment: "I have to pass date parameter values to code: - so is the error coming from how you are passing//converting that value, rather than from the part of the query you showed?

Comment: @Akhira I can't find the `GYT` time zone for Guyana in Oracle but you can use `FROM_TZ( created_date, '-04:00' ) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` to convert from UTC-4 to UTC (or substitute whatever other time zones you require).

Comment: The function I put in the query was showing as expected in oracle, but when I embed that converted date to tableau, then it shows as not a valid month, so I am not sure why I am getting this error.

Comment: @MT0, thanks a lot for quick response

Comment: `FROM_TZ( created_date, 'America/Guyana' ) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'`

Comment: @MT0 In Oracle this works as expected: FROM_TZ( completed_date, '4:00' )  AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' it is doing minus fours, when I run the same query in Tableau, some how tableau is doing minus of 8 hours. So I made it to: FROM_TZ( completed_date, '0:00' )  then is doing a minus of 4 hours, not really sure why tableau is not doing the same way as oracle

Comment: thanks a lot for you help, @MT0, do you have any idea why tableau is doing -8 hours for when I kept as 4 as you showed?

Comment: The date field is not stored in this format 2020-11-29 14:06:46.963. Oracle internally stores Date in its 7 components  Century, date, month, year, hour, minute, seconds, and when you query date it is formate as per your nls_date_format parameter.

Comment: Okay thanks for your response @ Aman Singh Rajpoot, is it suggestable to use this formula FROM_TZ( completed_date, '0:00' )AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'AS TRANS_DATE  in tableau to achieve my requirement?